# Can't read Ojbect properties, always getting null

Tags: java, mysql

I have a `SpringMVC` web applicatioin, I set the value for a `Object property` in `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`:

```
public class SpringMVCFilter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Interceptor.ss = "foo"; // it's a static field
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
...more code hidden
}
```

Then, I getting the value in the MySQL `QueryInterceptor`:

```
public class Interceptor implements QueryInterceptor {
    public static String ss = null;
    @Override
    public <T extends Resultset> T postProcess(Supplier<String> sql, Query interceptedQuery, T originalResultSet, ServerSession serverSession) {
        System.out.println(ss); // I have set the value for 'ss' before
        return null;
    }
...more code hidden
}
```

`ss` is obviously a static variable, and I have assigned it a value, why can't I get the value in `QueryInterceptor`, they are in the some thread, but the `ss` always show `null`, the execution order is assigned first.

enviroment:
mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13
spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: There are only three possibilities here: 1. Your code setting `ss` isn't running before your code trying to use it. 2. Code you haven't shown is writing `null` back to `ss` after your code setting `ss` and before you try to use it. 3. (Unlikely, but I don't know Spring MVC) You have two separate copies of the class, because they were loaded by different classloaders.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think the reasion is 3, I printed the relevant information:<br>
[com.example.demo.HandlerInterceptor] DTO.value=foo
[com.example.demo.HandlerInterceptor] CLASSLOADER is org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@4393e362
[com.example.demo.Interceptor] DTO.value=null
[com.example.demo.Interceptor] CLASSLOADER is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@58644d46


How can I solve this problem, can you have any suggestions?

Comment: Wow. :-) I'm afraid you'd need a Spring MVC expert. I hope you get an answer!